# display message on command "cd production"

Tags: linux, shell

I wish to accomplish the following:

If I execute "cd production" on bash prompt, I should go into the directory and a message should be displayed "You are in production", so that the user gets warned.

Comment: Similar question there: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18532/show-message-when-cd-into-specific-directory

Answer (score 8):

Don't do it that way. :)

What you really want to know isn't whether the user just got into the 'production' directory via a cd command; what you really want to know is if you're modifying production data, and how you got there (cd, pushd, popd, opening a shell from a parent process in that directory already) is irrelevant.

It makes much more sense, then, to have your shell put up an obnoxious warning when you're in the production directory.

```
function update_prompt() {
  if [[ $PWD =~ /production(/|$) ]] ; then
    PS1="\u@\h \w [WARNING: PRODUCTION] $"
  else
    PS1="\u@\h \w $"
  fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=update_prompt
```

Feel free to replace the strings in question with something much more colorful.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by executing the following in the shell context (e.g., .bashrc).

```
xcd() {
    if [[ "$1" == "production" ]] ; then
        echo Warning, you are in production.
    fi
    builtin cd $1
}
alias cd=xcd
```

This creates a function then aliases the `cd` command to that function. The function itself provides the warning then calls the real `cd`.

A better solution, however, may be to detect real paths, since the solution you've asked for will give you a false positive for `"cd $HOME ; cd production"` and false negative for `"cd /production/x"` (if `/production` was indeed the danger area).

I would do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export xcd_warn="/home/pax /tmp"
xcd() {
    builtin cd $1

    export xcd_path=$(pwd)
    for i in ${xcd_warn} ; do
        echo ${xcd_path}/ | grep "^${i}/"
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
            echo Warning, you are in ${i}.
        fi
    done
}
alias cd=xcd
```

which will allow you to configure the top-level danger directories as absolute paths.

Comment: This does what the user asked for, but I think what they *need* is something different; they should care whether they're actually in the production directory, not whether they just issued a 'cd' command to get there -- if they got in via a pushd instead, the data is just as sensitive.

Comment: @Mark, make sure you add the smiley next time - it took a few seconds of looking for the error before I remembered what xkcd was :-) D'Oh!

Comment: That's a good point, @Charles, although you could just as easily alias the other commands as well. It may be that a combination of our methods would be best (your prompt command with the list of dangerous directories). However, it can never be foolproof because fools are so ingenious. A simple "rm -rf /production/important_stuff" won't be caught by either of our methods. I suspect the better option is to limit access to /production and below with file permissions, only allow competent people near production data and make sure backups are done right.

Comment: you dont need to unalias and re-alias the cd command. Just issue "builtin cd $1" instead.

Comment: Thanks, @camh, I've been looking for a more elegant way of doing that. Unalias-it/use-it/alias-it again was so crude.